Is the proof of proposition 2.29 from Elliptic Curves Number Theory And Cryptography incorrect?
Here is the proposition in question (Elliptic Curves Number Theory And Cryptography (2nd edition) p58):

PROPOSITION 2.29
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q$ is a power of the prime $p$. Let $r$ and $s$ be integers, not both 0. The endomorphism $r\phi_q + s$ is separable if and only if $p \nmid s$.
PROOF Write the multiplication by $r$ endomorphism as
$$
r(x,y) = (R_r(x),yS_r(x)).
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
(R_{r\phi_q}(x),yS_{r\phi_q}(x)) &= (\phi_q r)(x,y) = (R_r^q(x),y^{q}S_r^q(x)) \\
&= (R_r^q(x), y(x^3+Ax+B)^{(q-1)/2}S_r^q(x)).
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$
c_{r\phi_q} = R_{r\phi_q}'/S_{r\phi_q} = qR_r^{q-1}R_r'/S_{r\phi_q} = 0.
$$
Also, $c_s = R_s'/S_s = s$ by Proposition 2.28. By Lemma 2.26,
$$
R_{r\phi_q + s}'/S_{r\phi_q+s} = c_{r\phi_q + s} = c_{r\phi_q} + c_s = 0 + s = s.
$$
Therefore, $R_{r\phi_q+s}' \neq 0$ if and only if $p \nmid s$. $\blacksquare$

where

$\phi_q$ is the Frobenius map $\phi_q(x,y)=(x^q,y^q)$
$R(x)$ & $S(x)$ are rational functions
an endomorphism of $E(F_q)$ is defined (in the textbook) to be a homomorphism $f:E(\overline{F_q}) \rightarrow E(\overline{F_q})$ ($E$ defined over the algebraic closure of the field)


The statement uses $r\phi_q$ but the proof uses $\phi_qr$, and those 2 homomorphisms are not necessarily equal. The proposition still seems true, though, if we update the proof to rather be:
\begin{align*}
(R_{r\phi_q}(x),yS_{r\phi_q}(x)) &= (r\phi_q)(x,y) \\ &= (R_r(x^q),y^{q}S_r(x^q)) \\
&= (R_r(x^q), y(x^3+Ax+B)^{(q-1)/2}S_r(x^q)).
\end{align*}
because then
$$
c_{r\phi_q} = \frac{R_{r\phi_q}'(x)}{S_{r\phi_q}(x)} = \frac{R_r'(x)qx^{q-1}}{S_{r\phi_q}} = 0
$$

Is this correct?

Who's the author, if you don't mind?

Lawrence C Washington https://www.amazon.com/Elliptic-Curves-Cryptography-Mathematics-Applications/dp/1420071467

I agree that I don't see a reason why would someone use $(r\circ \phi_q)(x,y)$ instead of $(\phi_q \circ r)(x,y)$.
However, you say that those endomorphisms are not necessarily equal, which is not the case here. They are actually equal because $[r]$ is a multiplication by $r$ map and it has coefficients from $\mathbb{F}_q$, which can be seen using division polynomials (Chapter 3.2 of Washington or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_polynomials) since their equations depend only on $A,B\in\mathbb{F}_q$. But those are introduced after this proof..., not sure how to see it without it with the tools of Chapter 2.
So $r(x,y) = (a(x,y), b(x,y))$ where $a(x,y),b(x,y)\in \mathbb{F}_q[x,y]$ and it holds that $[r]\circ \phi_q = \phi_q \circ [r]$ because $\forall \alpha\in \mathbb{F}_q: \alpha = \alpha^q$ and also if $\alpha\in \overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ s.t. $\phi_q(\alpha)=\alpha$ then $\alpha\in \mathbb{F}_q$. In other words, $\phi_q$ fixes exactly elements of $\mathbb{F}_q$ (C.2 in Washington).
In general, $\phi_q$ commutes with any endomorphism which has coefficients only in $\mathbb{F}_q$.
I hope I havent made any mistakes since its a long time I did anything with curves.

Thanks, that's very helpful!
